# Site Redirect issue only on dektop device and home page

Tags: redirect, caching

I have a redirect issue on [https://lifeatdubai.com/](https://stackoverflow.com) this site only on dektop device.

I restored the previous backup,cleared the cache,Re-uploaded the .htaccess file, but still have the issue.

I also added this issue to wp forum [https://wordpress.org/support/?post_type=topic&p=16903030](https://stackoverflow.com). You can see the fully one click on this link.